# How to read complex data in array/JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been facing really hard times to read a bunch of data in JSON using json_decode() function in PHP. Basically I need to read basic data to display flights dates origins and destinations.

This is how it should be:

```
20 solutions found.

Solution#   1   Sale Price: BRL2919.54
         Slice 0
             TA 916 GRU 2015-06-16T06:15-03:00 LIM 2015-06-16T09:20-05:00
             AV 962 LIM 2015-06-16T10:04-05:00 MIA 2015-06-16T16:48-04:00
```

And this is the JSON code: http://pastebin.com/dH16RriT

When I try to transform that and read it comes with NULL data.

```
$data = json_decode($results, true); // $results is a variable with
the JSON content from the URL above

echo $data['tripOption']['saleTotal']; // just an example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , you should use

```
print_r($a['trips']['tripOption'][0]['saleTotal'])
```

if you want to read the data inside that array,you can do as follows:

```
$data = json_decode($s,true);
foreach ($data['trips']['tripOption'] as $item){
    print_r($item['saleTotal'] . "\n");
};
```

Comment: Perfect, that make sense. If I had to read the data inside that array, how would be? Do I have to use foreach to read all answers?

Comment: if my answer is useful for you ,please vote up my answer,thank !

Comment: Yes it was, thank you! What if I need to get data from inside of more complex array, like "carrier"? I have to walk thought all the arrays before to get it?

Like: echo $dados['trips']['tripOption']['slice']['segment']['flight']['carrier']; ? This is not working by the way

Comment: yes.I think there is not other method.before you know what's in a array,you cannot get the column in it .

Comment: It is not working... I'm not having good times with that array hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem to decode that data from the json structure you posted. Here is a trivial example script which dumped the decoded array structure:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('./data.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data);
```

About the specific data you try and fail to extract: you have to take care to use the correct "path" inside the data structure. This one works:

```
print_r($data['trips']['tripOption']);
```

Since that one is an array yo have to address a specific entry in there to get the output you expect:

```
echo $data['trips']['tripOption'][0]['saleTotal']; // just an example
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You are absolute right, I'm having problem addressing it. For example, to get "carrier" which is 6th of the hierarchy, that is not woring: $data['trips']['tripOption']['slice']['segment']['flight']['carrier'];

Comment: Same thing: you look at the same location in the hierarchy. Again you try to address the element `slice` in the array `tripOption` which is a numeric array, so only offers numeric keys. Usually it helps to reduce the expression and dump part of the array for debugging purposes, here to `print_r( $data['trips']['tripOption']);` and then check and add a single hierarchiy level at a time. So you kind of feel your way forward.